# Unity3D programatically changing anchors - how it affects position

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine

in Unity3D when I move the anchors of an object in the editor, it stays in its place, probably because the editor automatically modifies something.

But when I change them(the anchors) programatically in script, the object changes its position.

I know I can just store the position and set it again after I change the anchors, in order to preserve position, but what I am asking is - does anyone know how exactly does changing the anchors at run-time, affect the position?

Is there a specific formula they follow?

Comment: This is a really hard question. I've been wondering about this too.

Comment: @Programmer never seen it asked anywhere either, I think it moves somehow along with the anchor

Comment: You are right! When in the `Editor` you change the anchor point of an element, its `transform position` is also recalculated, however at run-time this `transform position` is not recalculated, I guess its just how `Unity` works. As an example: Lets say you have a button with **position = (0, 0)** and **anchor position = (0, 0)**, in the `Editor` if you move the **anchor to (1, 1)** the button will now change **position to (-1, -1)** But at run-time the **position stays at (0, 0)** _moving_ the button on top of the **anchor at (1, 1)**.

Comment: @Hristo so first it changes the position at the opposite of what the anchor position is. But then it does another position change along with the scale(it squishes it and moves the center). So step 1 is the initial position change, but step 2 - i have no idea how it's determined, the values all look random to me.

Comment: @shortage_radeon Could you update the question with the code you are using and the exact values you are getting for the anchor and button position and of course the desired situation.

Comment: @Hristo well I haven't coded it yet, I just noticed that when you move the anchors, the object moves in the opposite direction of where you move them to.

Comment: @shortage_radeon are you moving the anchors via `script` or via `editor`?

Comment: @Hristo when I move them via editor, it adjusts the positions. When I move them via script it doesn't adjust them, so I see that the positions change at the opposite direction of where I move the anchors